# Visual Studio 2005 offers 2 of each column-type control in my DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, checkbox

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 on Windows XP.
I'm not sure if these problems are related or not.

When I drop a new DataGridView into my Windows Forms, and try to make 1 of the columns a checkBox, VS2005 gives me *TWO* of each columnType choice:

```
TextBox
TextBox
CheckBox
CheckBox
ComboBox
ComboBox
etc
etc
```

Is that normal?  Should I use "CheckBox type 1" or "type 2"?

Also,

When I make 1 of my columns a "checkBox", and then try to use it, the checkBox seems keep turning itself back ON.

I turn it ON, and then click on a different column or row, and the checkbox stays ON, like it should.

But if I turn the checkBox OFF, and then click on a different column or row, the checkbox magically turns itself back ON.  Huh?

I can't find anything in my code that says "turn it back on".  And I've never connected it directly to any data source.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Both of those issue are very strange. I think that there is either a third party control or a user control that has inherited from DataGridView or your visual studio installation is corrupt.

I would recommend looking at the form designer.vb file to see what data type the DataGridView is or if something doesn't look quite right.

To view the designer.vb, select `Show All Files` from the `Project` menu, then expand the form in question and double-click on the designer.vb file.

You can also get to this file by right-clicking on a reference to the DataGridView (or any control) in your form code (not designer) and selecting `Go To Definition`; this will take you to the designer file.

If this project was migrated from an earlier version of VB.Net, there is a chance that the form elements are stored directly in the form code file in the region `" Windows Form Designer generated code "`. If this is the case, the second method above for getting to the control definition will work or you can just search for the name of the control starting from the top of the file.

At any rate, once you get to the control definition, it should look similar to this:

```
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.DataGridView1 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
    Me.Column1 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
    Me.Column2 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    CType(Me.DataGridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'DataGridView1
    '
    Me.DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn() {Me.Column1, Me.Column2})
    Me.DataGridView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(68, 84)
    Me.DataGridView1.Name = "DataGridView1"
    Me.DataGridView1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(240, 150)
    Me.DataGridView1.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'Column1
    '
    Me.Column1.HeaderText = "Column1"
    Me.Column1.Name = "Column1"
    '
    'Column2
    '
    Me.Column2.HeaderText = "Column2"
    Me.Column2.Name = "Column2"

    ... some additional stuff

    Me.Controls.Add(Me.DataGridView1)
    CType(Me.DataGridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
End Sub
Friend WithEvents DataGridView1 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
Friend WithEvents Column1 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents Column2 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```

If the data types are different than System.Windows.Forms, then the problem is with that component.

If the data types are the same, then you can try a couple of things:

1) Close the solution and manually clear the bin directories to remove any potential confusing references. Then open the project again.

2) If 1 doesn't work, painful as it is, I would suggest uninstalling and reinstalling visual studio (I just had to do this yesterday for VS2010 due to strange behavior).

Comment: You are onto something there.  I just tried to create a brand new project.  There, DataGridView only offers *ONE* of each (not 2) columnType choices.  I'm thinking my application is somehow damaged/confused... and not VS2005 as a whole.

Comment: Deleting/recreating my BIN folder didn't help... but I'll try some of your other ideas tomorrow.

Comment: All my data types in the design code, look normal. Maybe a bug? What's the easiest way to find the version number of the DataGridView I'm using?  What's the latest from Microsoft?